# Avoid injection risk with MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, security

I have this function and I want to change the function so that there is no risk of injection. The function retrieves the form information:

```
function retrieve(){

    if(isSet($_POST['text'])|| $_POST['text']==" ") return null;
    return $_POST['text'];
}
```

Comment: You have an undefined variable `$texte`

Comment: Looks safe to me, though completely pointless...

Comment: I believe with MongoDB, you need to be careful with PHP's POST array device. If you cast values to int/float/string you should be fine. You're not doing that here, so perhaps look into that, and what risks it can cause?

Comment: Try removing any $ at the beginning and checking for array structures when de-serialised

Answer (score 0):

I think I found with htmlentities:

```
function retrieve(){

    if(isSet($_POST['text'])|| $_POST['text']==" ") return null;
    return htmlentities($_POST['text']);
}
```

Comment: This will error on some injections, such as array injections